# Facebook activity feed height, in Safari

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Im trying to get a Facebook likebox+feed from a Facebook Page to show correctly on my webpage.

I am having trouble with the height in Safari, and apparently in some Chrome versions.

I cant post images because I am only on 6 in reputation.
So Ill have to try to explain:

In my Firefox and my Chrome browsers everything is ok.

But in my Safari browser and my collegues Chrome browser the Facebook likebox showing is not the correct height. It is set to and supposed to be 1200px high. But is only showing aprox 395px.
The div container it is placed in is not set to a specific height.

This is how I implement:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/Citysingler" data-width="400" data-height="1200" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>
```

The problem online: (it is the feed in the right column):
http://www.citysingler.dk/Gaestebog/98

Any idea how to make this look right, crossbrowser?

Thx
John

Comment: If the problem is on your website, you should show us your website.

Comment: Ah! Ofcourse, sorry. Added in edit.